# How to type guard a get method on an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object that contains values accessed from a get method. I want to type the get method such that it infers the return values from the key.

I'm using TS 3.6.2 and have got a working type using overloading that looks like this:

```js
interface Values {
    foo: FooType;
    bar: BarType;
    baz: BazType;
}

interface ObjectWithGetter {
   get(key: 'foo'): Values['foo'];
   get(key: 'bar'): Values['bar'];
   get(key: 'baz'): Values['baz'];
}
```

It seems like I should be able to condense the overloaded get type into something like:

```
get(key: keyof Values): Values[key];
```

But key is a variable in this case and this is not a valid type.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is generics:

```js
interface ObjectWithGetter {
   get<K extends keyof Values>(key: K): Values[K];
}
```

Introducing the generic parameter `K` allows you to "re-use" the key for selecting the right return type.